# Xamarin Forms open DatePicker from code on UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, datepicker, nullable

Trying to make a custom control in xamarin forms to handle nullable dates. There seems to be a fair few examples out there which cover iOS and Android but they don't cover UWP as well. I've got it all setup but the problem comes when you have an invisible datePicker and call .focus() on it the datePicker flyout pops up for both iOS and Android but this doesn't work for UWP.

Does anyone know how to open up the UWP DatePicker from code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using invisible `DatePicker` try using `DatePickerFlyout` directly. You can instantiate it using its parameterless constructor and then use `ShowAtAsync` method to display it at a particular location:

```
var flyout = new DatePickerFlyout();
await flyout.ShowAtAsync(myButton); //show the flyout at a button
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the reply. I've put this code into my xamarin forms shared project and wrapped it round to only run if device type is UWP, all sweet so far. The problem I have is that the ShowAtAsync method requires a FrameworkElement to be provided to it and being it's in the Xamarin Forms Shared Project the parent Grid that it's being called from on touch is not allowed to be passed into the ShowAtAsync method as it errors saying it's not a valid FrameworkElement. Any ideas?